# Button that changes the language at runtime does not work the first time

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create two buttons at the top of a LinearLayout that will allow the user to change the language of the application. However, the first time I press any of these buttons, it will only recreate (Via the recreate() method) the page but will not change the language. The second time will change the language but If I press a different button that will take me to another Intent and then go back it will change the language to the original value. Only after the third time the language will change for the whole app.

I've tried almost everything provided in SO. 
Changed the xml attributes (see below), update to the not depricated version of the Locale() method, change the Button to ImageButto and included the onFocusChange .

#### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartPage"
    android:background="#404040"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:background="#404040">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/enT"
            android:layout_width="91dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="actionEN"
            android:tag="@drawable/enflag"
            android:textColor="#FFB33636" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="229dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/grT"
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="actionGR"
            android:text="GR"
            android:textColor="#FFB33636" />
        />

    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="7px"
        android:background="#FFB33636"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="#252525"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### OnFocusChange

```
input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    v.performClick();
                }
            }
        });
```

#### Current Code

```
translateToEn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.enT);
```

```
 public void actionEN(View view) {

        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = getBaseContext().getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLocale(locale);
        } else {
            configuration.locale = locale;
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        recreate();
    }
```

The problem is that everything I tried first recreates the view, and only the second time translates the page.

Comment: I looked at my app, and I have exactly the same code than in your method actionEN(). Don't you reinit the Locale in onCreate or onResume?

Comment: @FlorentBreton The actionEN is being called inside the onCreate. The last line of the method recreates the app. However, even though I can see that the page is being reloaded, it is never translated.

Comment: You call actionEN in onCreate? That means you loop with the creation of your activity since you call recreate() in your onCreate method. That's not good